# (Non-)Hermiticity of Dirac operator

Tags: conventions, dirac-equation, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices, wick-rotation

I have a Dirac operator given by
\begin{equation}
D\!\!\!/[A, A^{5}]=\gamma^\mu D_\mu=\gamma^\mu (\partial_{\mu} - {\rm i}  A_{\mu} - {\rm i}  \gamma_{5} A_{\mu}^{5}),
\end{equation}
where $A_{\mu}$ and $A^{5}_{\mu}$ are Hermitian.

In the Euclidean space, I can show that the Dirac operator is Hermitian $D\!\!\!/[A,A^{5}]= D\!\!\!/^{\dagger}[A,A^{5}]$ using $\gamma^{\mu\dagger}= -\gamma^{\mu}$, $\gamma^{5} \gamma^{\mu}=-\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{5}$ and $\partial^{\dagger}_{\mu} =- \partial_{\mu}$.
When $A^{5}_{\mu}=0$, [it has been also shown](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/373202/hermiticity-of-dirac-operator-gamma-mud-mu-and-expansion-in-eigenmodes?rq=1) that the Dirac operator is anti-Hermitian with respect to the inner product such that $\overline{D\!\!\!/}[A,0]=-D\!\!\!/[A,0]$, where $\overline{D\!\!\!/}={D\!\!\!/}^{\dagger} \gamma^{0}$.

I now wish to find relations between $\overline{D\!\!\!/}$, $D\!\!\!/$ and ${D\!\!\!/}^{\dagger}$ for $A=0$ and $A^{5}\neq 0$ in both Minkowski and Euclidean space. For this purpose, I've tried to evaluate the adjoint/Hermitian conjugate of the last term in the Dirac operator as

- Adjoint

\begin{equation}
\overline{- {\rm i}  \gamma^{\mu}  \gamma_{5} A_{\mu}^{5}}
= {\rm i} A_{\mu}^{5} \overline{ \gamma^{\mu }  \gamma_{5} } 
= {\rm i} A_{\mu}^{5}  \gamma_{5} \gamma^{\mu \dagger} \gamma^{0}
= {\rm i} A_{\mu}^{5}  \gamma_{5}   \gamma^{0} \underbrace{\gamma^{0} \gamma^{\mu \dagger} \gamma^{0}}_{\gamma^{\mu } }
= {\rm i} A_{\mu}^{5}  \gamma_{5}   \gamma^{0} \gamma^{\mu } 
= {\rm i} A_{\mu}^{5}  \gamma^{0}   \gamma^{\mu }  \gamma_{5}  ,
\end{equation}

- Hermitian conjugate
  \begin{equation}
  (- {\rm i}  \gamma^{\mu}  \gamma_{5} A_{\mu}^{5})^{\dagger}
  =
   {\rm i}   A_{\mu}^{5}  \gamma_{5} \gamma^{\mu \dagger} 
  =
  \begin{cases}
   - {\rm i}   A_{\mu}^{5}  \gamma_{5} \gamma^{\mu } & \text{in Euclidean space} ,\\
  \\
   {\rm i}   A_{\mu}^{5}  \gamma_{5} \gamma^{0} \gamma^{\mu } \gamma^{0} & \text{in Minkowski space}.
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
  Except for the known relation $D\!\!\!/ [0, A^{5}]= {D\!\!\!/}^{\dagger}[0, A^{5}]$ in the Euclidean space, I can't see any (anti-)Hermiticity relations between $\overline{D\!\!\!/}$,  ${D\!\!\!/}^{\dagger}$ and $D\!\!\!/$.
  Does this mean that $D\!\!\!/[0, A^{5}]$ is non-Hermitian, or did I miss something in my calculations?